# Docker: how to grant root privileges to the jenkins user

Tags: shell, jenkins, sh

I have a "docker-jenkins" container with some configured tasks that in the post-build have to run a shell script that move the builded data to a new folder inside the container and then commit to SVN repo.

My problem is that the SH script is executed by "jenkins" user that has not root privileges so my script fails with "permission denied" error.

How can I grant more privileges to jenkins user? Or how can I run the SH script with root privileges?

I'm using Jenkins CI inside a docker container so I suppose that I have to run some docker commands to grant more privileges to jenkins user...

Any ideas?

Comment: Depending on your container OS, you could install sudo in the container, then add the jenkins user to the sudo group.

Comment: This seems extremely midirected. You migtht want to grant _very limited_ `sudo` rights to the Jenkins user, but simply making the destination writable by this user seems vastly superior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Giving the correct permissions to the destination folder I can solve this kind of problem. SUDO rights are ok too but it could become a security problem.